# Bug in generated Button control template on Windows 7

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, controltemplate, windows-themes

I have two computers, one at home and another at work. Both use the same VS2017 Professional ver 15.8.4 but with different OS: One with Windows 10, the other with Windows 7.
On both I created a new WPF-Project (.Net Framework 4.5) containing a Button. If I let generate a template for the particular button via *Properties > Template > Convert to Local Value*, the ControlTemplates look different on each machine.

**XAML of the Windows 10-Template:**

```
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFBEE6FD"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFC4E5F6"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF2C628B"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFBCDDEE"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF245A83"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FFADB2B5"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF838383"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

**XAML of the Windows 7-Template:**

```
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding IsDefaulted}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Themes:ButtonChrome>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="RenderDefaulted" TargetName="Chrome" Value="True"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="True"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFADADAD"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

On Windows 7 it also adds a new namespace:

```
xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
```

The problem is, that on Windows 7 the generated code is faulty:

```
The name "ButtonChrome" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
```

How can I prevent generating the faulty template on Windows 7?

Comment: It should be expected to be different on different OSs because Windows 7 and Windows 10 have different theme based templates.  The missing reference still seems like a problem though.

Comment: @Bradley Uffner: Thank You for Your comment. 'Theme' is THE clue to follow to get a proper solution.